# Finding the median of an array of floating point numbers

Tags: groovy

I've looked through all the examples in here already of this and nothing quite answers my question. I'm very new to Groovy.

I want to create something like a list or an array of floating point numbers, prices such as 239.99.

I then want to pass that array or list to a method that will determine the median price in that array or list of numbers. The total size will vary.

Is there any quick and easy code to do this? How do I add each number to the array or list and must I use doubles?

Any help is appreciated, this one has me stuck and frustrated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073174/groovy--means--medians--modes--and-ranges-calculations.html

Comment: The only problem with that example is I'm not using a groovy script, I'm using a groovy program/project and several of the variables like median and mean are not defined. Are they floats, integers, strings, a huge ball of fluff? Doesn't translate into what I need.

Comment: I've gotten most of it to work but the median formula is giving me a nasty error. median = numberItems %2 != 0 ? values[midNumber] : (values[midNumber] + values[midNumber-1])/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following function determines the [median](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median) for non-empty lists.

```
def median(data) {
    def copy = data.toSorted()
    def middle = data.size().intdiv(2)

    // you can omit the return in groovy for the last statement
    data.size() % 2 ? copy[middle] : (copy[middle - 1] + copy[middle]) / 2
}
```

It works with all types that support addition and division.

For example:

```
assert median([1, 7, 4, 3]) == 3.5
assert median([1, 7, 4]) == 4
assert median([1, 7]) == 4
assert median([1]) == 1
assert median([1.7, 3.4, 10.9, 4.2]) == 3.8
```

In terms of what you can do with lists check the [Lists overview](http://groovy-lang.org/groovy-dev-kit.html#Collections-Lists) and then the [List API](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html).

Comment: The third line won't pass. "Cannot resolve symbol intdiv".

Comment: What groovy version are you using and what container do you hand into the median function?